# Getting JavaCV 0.9 platform binaries to download automatically with SBT

Tags: sbt, javacv

I have an SBT application that is using JavaCV on Windows.

My build.sbt brings in JavaCV and its dependencies using:

```
classpathTypes += "maven-plugin"

libraryDependencies += "org.bytedeco" % "javacv" % "0.9"
```

This pulls JavaCV and its dependents (JavaCPP), but it isn't pulling the JAR with the platform specific libraries (opencv-windows-x86_64.jar).  This allows me to build, but I get "UnsatisfiedLinkError: no jniopencv_core in java.library.path"

Based on http://www.warski.org/blog/2014/01/using-javacv-with-sbt I also tried

```
libraryDependencies += "org.bytedeco" % "javacv" % "0.9" classifier "windows-x86_64"
```

SBT fails trying to resolve that dependency because it is looking for  http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bytedeco/javacv/0.9/javacv-0.9-windows-x86_64.jar which doesn't exist.

If I copy opencv-windows-x86_64.jar to the lib directory then everything works, but that defeats the point of using a dependency manager.

Does anyone know how to make SBT properly resolve the platform specific jars for JavaCV 0.9?

Answer (score 0):

Using the `-Dplatform.dependencies=true` option on the command line should do the trick!

Comment: I tried that and it didn't help.  The JARs I cactually need are inside of http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bytedeco/javacv/0.9/javacv-0.9-bin.zip 
I'm wondering if that's a nonstandard place and there is no way to get them to load.

Comment: @Dave That's a ZIP file, for manual installation. It basically contains the same files as the JAR files found spread around inside `http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/bytedeco/`, which can all be used by SBT or Maven. Those are "standard". It just seems like SBT doesn't like the Maven tricks I've been using...

Comment: Thanks Samuel, now I see how it is set up.  I can at least specify dependencies manually, and this will help me figure out why SBT isn't resolving.

Comment: @DaveDeCaprio Looks like SBT does not and will not support what we need: http://stackoverflow.com/a/25994063/523744  Could you make recommendations as to what we could do?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote an SBT plugin to make OpenCV dependency handling (yes, including platform dependencies) a one liner: https://github.com/lloydmeta/sbt-opencv

Simply add this to your `project/plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.beachape" % "sbt-opencv" % "1.4")
```

Comment: I'll try this out.  Thanks!