# SBT not resolving transitive dependencies in the <Profile> section of POM

Tags: scala, sbt, scala-2.10

If the POM.xml of a dependency has transitive dependencies inside "Profile" section of pom.xml then those dependencies are not resolved by SBT whereas they are resolved by Maven.
Eg:
when the following dependency is included in a project.....

```
   <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.hbase</groupId>
        <artifactId>hbase-client</artifactId>
        <version>0.98.0-hadoop2</version>
    </dependency>
```

...then the following dependencies are not resolved by SBT but are resolved by maven  :

```
hadoop-annotations , hadoop-mapreduce-client-core , hadoop-auth , hadoop-common
```

Can someone help me understand why this difference in resolution and how can I make SBT include these transient dependencies.

Following is test build.sbt used :

```
name := "StreamMaker"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.98.0-hadoop2" 

net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
```

Following is the entry in hbase-client's pom.xml :

```
    <profile>
  <id>hadoop-2.0</id>
  <activation>
    <property>
        <name>!hadoop.profile</name>
    </property>
  </activation>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-common</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
          <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
          <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
          <artifactId>jasper-compiler</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>tomcat</groupId>
          <artifactId>jasper-runtime</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-auth</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-mapreduce-client-core</artifactId>
      <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.sun.jersey.jersey-test-framework</groupId>
        <artifactId>jersey-test-framework-grizzly2</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.apache.hadoop</groupId>
      <artifactId>hadoop-annotations</artifactId>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</profile>
```

Depedencies resolved by SBT 0.13.5 :

```html
+-org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:0.98.0-hadoop2
  +-com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:1.3.9-1
  +-com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1
  | +-com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
  | 
  +-com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0
  +-commons-codec:commons-codec:1.7
  +-commons-io:commons-io:2.4
  +-commons-lang:commons-lang:2.6
  +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
  +-io.netty:netty:3.6.6.Final
  +-junit:junit:4.11
  | +-org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
  | 
  +-log4j:log4j:1.2.17
  +-org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:0.98.0-hadoop2
  | +-com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:1.3.9-1
  | +-com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:2.5.0
  | +-junit:junit:4.11
  | | +-org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3
  | | 
  | +-log4j:log4j:1.2.17
  | 
  +-org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:3.4.5
  | +-log4j:log4j:1.2.15 (evicted by: 1.2.17)
  | +-log4j:log4j:1.2.16 (evicted by: 1.2.17)
  | +-log4j:log4j:1.2.17
  | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1
  | +-org.slf4j:slf4j-log4j12:1.6.1
  |   +-log4j:log4j:1.2.15 (evicted by: 1.2.17)
  |   +-log4j:log4j:1.2.16 (evicted by: 1.2.17)
  |   +-log4j:log4j:1.2.17
  |   +-org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.6.1
  |   
  +-org.cloudera.htrace:htrace-core:2.04
  | +-com.google.guava:guava:12.0.1
  | | +-com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9
  | | 
  | +-commons-logging:commons-logging:1.1.1
  | +-org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:6.1.26
  | 
  +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:1.8.8
    +-org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:1.8.8
```

Dependencies resolved by Maven 3.0.4 :

```html
- org.apache.hbase:hbase-client:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2:compile
  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-common:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2:compile
  |  \- commons-collections:commons-collections:jar:3.2.1:compile
  +- org.apache.hbase:hbase-protocol:jar:0.98.0-hadoop2:compile
  +- commons-codec:commons-codec:jar:1.7:compile
  +- commons-io:commons-io:jar:2.4:compile
  +- commons-lang:commons-lang:jar:2.6:compile
  +- commons-logging:commons-logging:jar:1.1.1:compile
  +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:12.0.1:compile
  |  \- com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:jar:1.3.9:compile
  +- com.google.protobuf:protobuf-java:jar:2.5.0:compile
  +- io.netty:netty:jar:3.6.6.Final:compile
  +- org.apache.zookeeper:zookeeper:jar:3.4.5:compile
  +- org.cloudera.htrace:htrace-core:jar:2.04:compile
  |  \- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty-util:jar:6.1.26:compile
  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:1.8.8:compile
  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
  |  +- commons-cli:commons-cli:jar:1.2:compile
  |  +- org.apache.commons:commons-math:jar:2.1:compile
  |  +- xmlenc:xmlenc:jar:0.52:compile
  |  +- commons-httpclient:commons-httpclient:jar:3.1:compile
  |  +- commons-net:commons-net:jar:3.1:compile
  |  +- org.mortbay.jetty:jetty:jar:6.1.26:compile
  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-core:jar:1.9:compile
  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-json:jar:1.9:compile
  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jettison:jettison:jar:1.1:compile
  |  |  |  \- stax:stax-api:jar:1.0.1:compile
  |  |  +- com.sun.xml.bind:jaxb-impl:jar:2.2.3-1:compile
  |  |  |  \- javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api:jar:2.2.2:compile
  |  |  |     \- javax.activation:activation:jar:1.1:compile
  |  |  +- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-jaxrs:jar:1.8.3:compile
  |  |  \- org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-xc:jar:1.8.3:compile
  |  +- commons-el:commons-el:jar:1.0:runtime
  |  +- net.java.dev.jets3t:jets3t:jar:0.6.1:compile
  |  +- commons-configuration:commons-configuration:jar:1.6:compile
  |  |  +- commons-digester:commons-digester:jar:1.8:compile
  |  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils:jar:1.7.0:compile
  |  |  \- commons-beanutils:commons-beanutils-core:jar:1.8.0:compile
  |  +- org.apache.avro:avro:jar:1.7.4:compile
  |  |  +- com.thoughtworks.paranamer:paranamer:jar:2.3:compile
  |  |  \- org.xerial.snappy:snappy-java:jar:1.0.4.1:compile
  |  +- com.jcraft:jsch:jar:0.1.42:compile
  |  \- org.apache.commons:commons-compress:jar:1.4.1:compile
  |     \- org.tukaani:xz:jar:1.0:compile
  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-auth:jar:2.2.0:compile
  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-mapreduce-client-core:jar:2.2.0:compile
  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-common:jar:2.2.0:compile
  |  |  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-yarn-api:jar:2.2.0:compile
  |  |  +- com.google.inject:guice:jar:3.0:compile
  |  |  |  +- javax.inject:javax.inject:jar:1:compile
  |  |  |  \- aopalliance:aopalliance:jar:1.0:compile
  |  |  +- com.sun.jersey:jersey-server:jar:1.9:compile
  |  |  |  \- asm:asm:jar:3.1:compile
  |  |  \- com.sun.jersey.contribs:jersey-guice:jar:1.9:compile
  |  \- com.google.inject.extensions:guice-servlet:jar:3.0:compile
  +- org.apache.hadoop:hadoop-annotations:jar:2.2.0:compile
  |  \- jdk.tools:jdk.tools:jar:1.7:system
  +- com.github.stephenc.findbugs:findbugs-annotations:jar:1.3.9-1:compile
  \- junit:junit:jar:4.11:compile
     \- org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:jar:1.3:compile
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sbt does not handle maven profiles.
You should add the dependencies (mentioned in given profile) to your sbt file.

```
name := "StreamMaker"

version := "1.0"

scalaVersion := "2.10.4"

resolvers += "Local Maven Repository" at "file://"+Path.userHome.absolutePath+"/.m2/repository"

libraryDependencies += "org.apache.hbase" % "hbase-client" % "0.98.0-hadoop2" 

// Add the dependencies from the active profile.
libraryDependencies ++= Seq("org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-core" % "2.2.0",
                            "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-mapreduce-client-jobclient" % "2.2.0",
                            "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-hdfs" % "2.2.0",
                            "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-auth" % "2.2.0",
                            "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-common" % "2.2.0",
                            "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-client" % "2.2.0",
                            "org.apache.hadoop" % "hadoop-annotations" % "2.2.0")

net.virtualvoid.sbt.graph.Plugin.graphSettings
```

See [this discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/simple-build-tool/ZgLwFo9CQI8).

Quoting Josh:

> Maven does allow this, but it's kind of bad form.  How do you know
>   which profile was active for deployment?  Changing dependencies based
>   on active profiles is *VERY* evil to your users.   I'd contact that
>   authors of the project and ask them to find an alternative method.

Comment: Thanks @Shyamendra. Any leads on how can we create a plugin or some code to augment SBT to automatically infer profile and pick dependencies,since listing down all the transient dependencies can be difficult, especially when even the transient dependencies have profiles.